# No SDK signal found for Facebook bidding through Google Ad Manager

Tags: android, google-ad-manager, mobile-ad-mediation, facebook-ads

I'm trying to ad facebook as a mediation partner with GAM (Google Ad Manager) and followed the doc from [FB](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/platform-setup/android/add-sdk) and [GAM](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/meta).

But when I try to test this using Ad Inspector, I'm getting that `No sdk signal found` error.

[image]

I know this process includes lots of steps/changes but please let me know if you've faced this or any clue what cloud be the reason.

Comment: have you solved it? I think you have to have the facebook app and you signed in. and you have to add test device.

Comment: also make sure to add your device hash in your code 
something like this:
`AdSettings.addTestDevice("your device hash you can find in the log cat")`

Comment: Are you loading ads after the Mobile ads initialization completed? It is important to wait for the initialization to complete before you load ads in order to ensure full participation from every ad network on the first ad request. Details here https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediate#troubleshooting_bidding

Comment: What is your solution ?

Comment: Updating the FB and GAM to latest SDK version fixes this issue for me. @neobie

Comment: @Ankit unfortunate not for me, even using latest version :( seems like only happen to banner ad